# nginx is not redirecting on port

Tags: redirect, nginx, port

I have set up domain to point A record to my VPS IP & added the following file  `/etc/nginx/conf.d/custom.conf`.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name researchnot.es .researchnot.es;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

I have run `service nginx configtest` which says all is ok and restarted nginx.

Comment: The server is listening on 80, yet you indicate forwarding from 443? Did you mean for the server to listen on 443?

Comment: I think just 80? for standard researchnot.es requests ?